Image not displaying despite everything else displaying
The image in the cart isn't displaying. Everything else is displayed correctly except for the image.
Cart.js
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAlert } from "react-alert";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { addToCart } from "../../actions/cartActions";
import Loader from "../layout/Loader";
import MetaData from "../layout/MetaData";

const Cart = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const alert = useAlert();
  const { cartItems } = useSelector((state) => state.cart);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <MetaData title={"Вашата количка"} />
      {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
        <h2 className="mt-5">Kоличката ви е празна</h2>
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <h2 className="mt-5" style={{ color: "#8da1ea" }}>
            Вашата количка: <b>{cartItems.lenght}</b>
          </h2>
          <div className="row d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div className="col-12 col-lg-8">
              {cartItems.map((item) => (
                <Fragment>
                  <hr />
                  <div className="cart-item">
                    <div className="row">
                      <div className="col-4 col-lg-3">
                        <img
                          src={item.image}
                          alt={item.name}
                          style={{ maxWidth: "100%", maxHeight: "100%", color: "#8da1ea" }}
                        />
                      </div>

                      <div className="col-5 col-lg-3">
                        <Link
                          to={`/products/${item.product}`}
                          style={{ color: "#8da1ea" }}
                        >
                          {item.name}
                        </Link>
                      </div>

                      <div className="col-4 col-lg-2 mt-4 mt-lg-0">
                        <p id="card_item_price">{item.price} Лв.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <hr />
                </Fragment>
              ))}
            </div>
            <div className="col-12 col-lg-3 my-4">
              <div id="order_summary">
                <h4 style={{ color: "#8da1ea" }}>Общо:</h4>
                <hr />
                <p style={{ color: "#8da1ea" }}>
                  Брой продукти:{" "}
                  <span className="order-summary-values">3 (Units)</span>
                </p>
                <p style={{ color: "#8da1ea" }}>
                  Обща цена:{" "}
                  <span className="order-summary-values">$765.56</span>
                </p>
                <hr />
                <button id="checkout_btn" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                  Плащане
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Cart;

cartActions.js where getting the information for the product is
import axios from 'axios';
import {ADD_TO_CART} from '../constants/cartConstants';

export const addToCart = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/v1/product/${id}`)

    dispatch({
        type: ADD_TO_CART,
        payload: {
            id: data.product._id,
            name: data.product.name,
            image: data.product.image,
            price: data.product.price
        }
    })

    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
}

I thought the error might be in the mapping but I think it's not there. I hope this code helps. That's pretty much the whole two files. Thanks in advance.

the problem might be src, you should check the url is accessible from item component
